# Cómo borrar un textbox que pasa informacion a una variable en el evento textchanged

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim precio, cantidad, resultado, existencia As Double
    existencia = Convert.ToDouble(txtdisponible.Text)
    precio = Convert.ToDouble(txtprecio.Text)
    cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(txtcantventa.Text)

    resultado = precio * cantidad
    txttotal.Text = resultado.ToString
    txtefectivo.Focus()
```

el código me funciona pero he estado probando y si por alguna razón ya llego a tener el foco en `txtcantventa` que equivale al valor que recibe la variable cantidad y presiono mi botón borrar me arroja este error:

> la cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debido a que en el momento de recuperar el valor de `txtcantventa` y convertirlo en `Double` te arroja dicho error.

```
cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(txtcantventa.Text)
```

---

**¿Cómo controlar la excepción FormatException?**

Para controlar dicho error, solo sería necesario usar [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Por ejemplo:

```
Double.TryParse(txtcantventa.Text, cantidad)
```